# Can not use session in model that is declared in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I can not use session variable in model that I have declared in controler.
this is the code. I have declare this session in dataOperate controller.

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('newrecord','new');
```

I use above session in model dataOperateModel

```
if($this->session->userdata('newrecode')){
       echo $this->session->userdata('newrecode');

       }
```

But it prints nothing. I have loaded session in autoload CodeIgniter. I cleared all session and tried again. but no luck. but when I use `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());` I can see newrecord session variable and other session variables. what has happend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled newrecord twice in your model. It says newrecode so if you copied this straight from your code editor you have found your problem.